# UIImage loaded from managed object data doesn't show up in UIImageView

Tags: ios, core-data, uiimageview

I've got a pretty simple iOS app (adapted from basic master-detail boilerplate).

I've got RestKit set up to load data from a server. If an object's image URL gets updated, I download the image (using an `AFHTTPClient` subclass) and save its data using `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)`. Pretty straightforward.

So now, I've got a database that's already populated with objects - including their `imageData`. But for some reason, though I can get a `UIImage` instance from the data, that `UIImage` won't show up in a `UIImageView`.

I've got a category on the auto-generated `NSManagedObject` subclass, which (among other things) pulls the image data, and returns a `UIImage` instance:

```
@implementation Artwork (Helpers)
// ...

- (UIImage*)image {
    if (self.imageData) {
        return [UIImage imageWithData:self.imageData];
    }
    return nil;
}

@end
```

In my detail view, I have a `UIImageView`, whose `image` is set from the above method. Here's the relevant bit from my detail view controller. It gets called just before the segue, and works fine for setting the description text, but doesn't set the image correctly.

```
- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item (a Artwork instance in this case).
    if (self.detailItem) {
        // this works just fine
        self.detailDescriptionText.text = self.detailItem.rawDescription;

        // ... but this doesn't! Nothing is shown in the 
        UIImage *image = self.detailItem.image;
        if (image) {
            // Yes, the UIImage *is* there
            NSLog(@"UIImage instance: %@, size: %fx%f", image, image.size.width, image.size.height);
            // ... but this doesn't seem to any effect
            self.imageView.image = image;
        }
    }
}
```

The `NSLog` call prints:

```
UIImage instance: <UIImage: 0x109a0d090>, size: 533.000000x300.000000
```

so it certainly seems like the `UIImage` object exists and has been unpacked from the data just like it should. But nothing shows up in the `UIImageView`.

Interestingly, if I set up a simple touch-listener on the detail view controller, I *can* show the image using the exact same code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIImage *image = self.detailItem.image;
    if (image) {
        NSLog(@"UIImage instance: %@, size: %fx%f", image, image.size.width, image.size.height);
        self.imageView.image = image;
    }
}
```

That works perfectly - tap the screen and the image shows up immediately, and the `NSLog` call prints:

```
UIImage instance: <UIImage: 0x10980a7e0>, size: 533.000000x300.000000
```

So there really *is* image data, and it *does* get unpacked into a proper `UIImage` - but it won't show up.

So, all in all, it seems like there's some sort of timing or threading issue. But here I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: Try set the image on the main thread: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) { /* your code here */ });

Comment: @AaronWojnowski Please, make that an answer so I can accept it :) I actually tried that earlier (having found similar questions and answers), but for whatever reason the app just hung when I did. But now it works fine, and does indeed set the image correctly

Comment: Beauty, glad it works - done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to set your image on the main thread :)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
    /* your code here */
});
```